# Proving an ideal is principal

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, where $\theta^3 - \theta + 4 = 0$. The ideal $I = <2, \theta>$ is principal in $O_K$. Find a generator of $I$.

That is the problem as stated in the book. I started off by saying that $a+b\theta$ is a generator of $I$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd{(a, b)} = 1$ because $O_K = \mathbb{Z}(\theta)$.

Therefore we have that $$<a+b\theta> = <2, \theta>$$ which implies that $$(a+b\theta)(c+d\theta) = 2(p+q\theta) + \theta(r+s\theta).$$

By expanding and comparing coefficients, I got that $$ac = 2p, ad+bc = 2q+r, bd = s$$ but I am unsure what to do after this and I don't understand how to incorporate the condition $\theta^3-\theta+4 = 0$.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Why are you so sure a generator of $I$ must be a $\mathbf Z$-linear combination of $1$ and $\theta$?  You are in a cubic field, so perhaps a generator will involve a $\theta^2$-term. (Also, the ring of integers is not just $\mathbf Z[\theta]$, since $(\theta^2-\theta)/2$ is integral over $\mathbf Z$.)

Comment: Look at norms of elements.  The first thing to try is $\theta + k$ for various small integers $k$ of both signs.  If you can find $k$ where $\theta + k$ has norm $\pm 2$ then $(\theta + k)$ has index $2$, and if $k$ is even then $(\theta + k) \subset (2,\theta)$ where both ideals have index $2$, so $(2,\theta) = (\theta + k)$.

Comment: Why is $(2, \theta) = (\theta + k)$ implied if both ideals have an index of $2$ and $(\theta+k) \subset (2, \theta)$? And by index, do you mean the absolute value of the norm?

Comment: The norm of an ideal is the index of the ideal.  For ideals $I$ and $J$ in $\mathcal  O_K$, if $I \subset J$ and $I$ and $J$ have the same index in $\mathcal O_K$, you ask why $I = J$.  This is just like in group theory: if $G$ is a group with subgroups $H$ and $H'$ such that $H \subset H'$ and $H$ and $H'$ have the same *finite* index in $G$, then $H = H'$.  If you can prove the result for groups then you'll see how to do it for ideals in $\mathcal O_K$.

Comment: I see how to finish off the problem now. If we let $k = 2$ then the norm of $(\theta + 2) = 2$ but what I am unable to see is how we prove that the norm of $(2, \theta)$ is $2$. I tried using the definition of the norm of an ideal, $N(J) = \sqrt{\frac{D(J)}{d(K)}}$ where $J = (2, \theta)$ but I am unable to find a basis for $J$ that has $3$ terms so I cannot take the determinant because the degree of the field is $3$.